# First Hover Image Disappears, Second Hover Image appears

Tags: css, image, hover

The css is pulling the image that allows me to swap images on hover. 
My Problem is, on my **first hover, image disappears**. Second hover, image appears. And the following hovers, everything works fine.

Why and how to solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because the first time you hover the browser has to request and download the new image from the server. This takes time and is the delay you see. Subsequent hovers work quickly because of browser caching.

You can, and should, avoid this by using [CSS sprites](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/).